# overlap between orbitting planets

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, circles, mathematical-astronomy

If two objects are orbiting around a common center point with different velocities and at different radius. The point in time in which they are overlapping can be found out using their angular velocities and calculating for a time at which the faster object is exactly 2pi ahead of the slower one. Is there any way possible to calculate this time of overlap for three, four, five, n different objects orbitting at different velocities and different radius? *think of it like the planets in the solar system in a 2D plane*

Comment: What do you mean by "overlapping"?

Comment: In the solar system orbit, an eclipse basically. In another analogy, the two hands of a clock and when they overlap.

Comment: Mathematically, I think you are asking for the line through the center of the circle and one of the objects to pass through one or more other objects. In general, this will never happen for three or more objects.

Comment: I think it most definately can. If three objects are moving at different velocities and at different radius, a time should be able to be found at which the three of them overlap shouldn't they. Like on some watches there are three hands and they do overlap. Even though this might be an insane number it should be possible no?

Comment: In general, no. Also, you needn't consider velocity and radius; angular velocity is all you have to consider. If the relative angular velocities are, say, 1, $\sqrt2$, and $\sqrt3$, then unless the bodies start in a very special position they will never line up exactly.

Comment: What if you apply the condition that they start at an overlap. How about then? I was thinking that if the overlap between the first two can be found and then the next two can also be found. The LCM of these two values should give the value for when they all overlap. but this doesn't seem to be right for some reason. Can you shed some light on this?

Comment: LCM applies to integers, and can be stretched to apply to rationals, but there's no such thing for real numbers in general. There is no sensible way to speak of the LCM of, say, 1 and $\sqrt2$, or 1 and $\pi$.

Comment: Any thoughts on my answer? or questions?

Comment: Yes that makes complete sense sir! Thank you :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's say we have three objects in orbit around a common center, at different angular velocities. The first two will line up with the center at some time; without loss of generality, let's call that time zero. They will line up again at times $p$, $2p$, $3p$, and so on, for some nonzero "period" $p$. The first and third objects will line up at some time $t$, and then again at $t+q$, $t+2q$, $t+3q$, and so on, for some period $q$. For all three to line up, we need integers $m$ and $n$ such that $$mp=t+nq$$ or to put it another way, $mp-nq=t$. So a necessary (but not sufficient) condition for the three objects to line up is that $t$ has to be in the field generated (over the rationals) by $p$ and $q$. But this does not happen, for example, if $p=\sqrt2$, $q=\sqrt3$, $t=\pi$. Indeed, there's a well-defined sense in which the probability of $t$ being in that field is zero. So, unless the angular velocities and starting times are exceedingly special, the three objects will never line up.

And what goes for three objects goes a fortiori for four or more objects.